# Is there anyway to to declare and use abstract methods in composable in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am trying to migrate a mixin in Vue 2 to composable in vue 3. This mixin was created using class component syntax and all the form UI components use this mixin.

In mixin we can declare abstract methods like the following example and we can also use the same method in another method definition in the same mixin. Please refer to how getType() method is used within show() method definition.

Is there any way we can implement a similar thing using composable? or is this considered a bad design while using composition API ?

```js
abstract class BaseForm<T> extends Vue{

  // declaration of methods that I want to be implemented in all the forms
  // Can we declare such abstract methods as composable as well? 
  abstract getType(): string;
        
  protected show() {
    ...
    const str = getType();
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have asked the same question, in different forms, two more times ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74009850/while-using-composition-api-is-there-any-way-to-re-use-props-that-are-common-fo), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74009811/how-to-migrate-a-generic-mixin-in-vue-2-to-generic-composable-in-vue-3)), within an interval of ~20 minutes. Consider deleting two of them and updating the remaining one according to [ask]. Please note spamming might get your [SO] privileges revoked.

Comment: @tao, I have intentionally asked three different questions, and please go through the details of those three queries. Those are not the same. All these three queries are related to migrating mixin in Vue 2 to Composable in Vue 3. But actual queries are different from each other. I do not have any intention of spamming. So please read all the three queries in detail